# How do I find hidden or omitted php parameters from a website I don't own?

Tags: php, api, url, hidden, optional-parameters

Given an arbitrary php website:

```
www.foo.com/search.php?lookfor=needle%20in%20haystack&pg=1
```

I want to figure out *all possible php parameters* that are omitted.

In the example above I can see two parameters: `lookfor` and `pg`
How do I find out which other parameters are supported?

My current strategy is to google for `www.foo.com/search.php?` and see if links come up that contain other parameters which I haven't yet seen, for example:

```
www.foo.com/search.php?lookfor=haystack%20in%20needle&secretoption=true
```

reveals yet another parameter called `secretoption`

This can be very frustrating and doesn't always work. Is there a better way to figure out the api structure? Is it for example possible to construct an url that would request all those options from a php server? I'm not a php expert.

Comment: You can't. And if there was such a mechanism, don't you think it would be a huge, huge security issue? If there's an API you use, refer to the documentation of that API, if there is one. There's no hacky way around getting the parameters that a PHP script (or any other language script or program) accepts.

Comment: Sorry, but this is not very helpful... I can think of at least one hacky way (brute force with dictionary, because not accepted parameters are ignored in most cases), but I'm looking for something more friendly and efficient.

Comment: Well, unless you kindly ask for the possible parameters, you can't find out what they are. You can do your dictionary thingy otherwise. The friendly way you're talking about is API documentation, be it in form of OPTIONS request or any other way. If there is no such thing, you can't make the remote server give you such info. That's just how stuff works.

Answer (score 1):

It’s not possible. PHP, like many other things, is executed on the server and nothing about its code is sent to the client/browser. Unless the owner of a site explicitely gives you information about what they accept (e.g. for an API), there is just no way to know this.

Any way to actually access such information would either mean that the server is vulnerable to huge security issues (since it would send out data that is supposed to be executed on the server only), or be something illegal since it would involve attacking the server or its infrastructure directly.

The only *real* way to get this information is to ask the owner to reveal the information. If you can provide a good reason that ends up being beneficial, it’s possible that they will agree.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the Tamper Data plugin for Firefox which shows all the header data that is posted and sent: 
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/tamper-data/

Turns out that for consistently programmed websites php parameter names often correspond to keys in POST requests and to keys in cookies. For example a POST key "page" was corresponding to the easily guessable php parameter "pg", which I was not able to find using my old google approach. The cookie key "mode" was corresponding to the php parameter "mode". Both parameters were not found by google. You can see that a parameter works if it changes the appearance of the website.

This is still an educated guess work, but it can be combined with my old google technique into something more reliable. There is only a few shortcut forms for each word. Furthermore parameters found by google can be compared with keys seen by using Tamper Data to help see an emerging naming pattern.

It also remains website friendly since it doesn't require comprehensive scans. You also don't need to wait for weeks in hope to get any response per email (And most of the time it's unrealistic to expect that you will)

Answer (score 0):

Joining late the party, but it is possible to infer some of them by bruteforcing. I agree that there's not such a thing as an API that offers you the list of all possible parameters (well, unless there are documented APIs...).

If you want still to have a try bruteforcing them, there are definitely some CTF tools helping.

Remember that using these tools without explicit authorization is not legal, in general.

https://www.sevenlayers.com/index.php/362-parameth-parameter-brute-force